# Raspberry Pi not receiving Arduino traffic

Tags: serial

I have a Arduino programmed to be ADC via serial commands for a Raspberry Pi, and I'm having problems establishing a link between the Raspberry Pi and the Arduino.
When I hold reset on the Arduino, serial works fine between the Raspberry Pi and the PC. Look:

[image]

But when I release the reset button, the Arduino does not "talk" to the Raspberry Pi, the "HELLO" message is not received:

[image]

But it can still receive messages from the PC, but not the Arduino:

[image]

The Arduino says `HELLO`, and the client needs to say `SYN`, then the Arduino `ACK`'s and `SYN`'s, followed by the `HELLO VERSION` message.

(This is a 3-way TCP inspired handshake: SYN, ACK/SYN, ACK).

What's the deal?

Connections: Arduino connected to PC via USB (CH340G) and the Raspberry Pi is connected to the Arduino via jumper cables and a voltage divider (that splits to 3.33V perfectly).

More info:
[image]

Comment: 3 way inspired handshake why? What's the physical interface? I2C ? SPI? Serial? Let's see your code

Comment: Just be 100% sure the comms work. It's serial. Here's the firmware: https://pastebin.com/QbJmrE7z

Comment: @Gala - The system (h/w & s/w) has not been "minimised" ([MCVE principle](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) to make this easy to solve, as currently presented. It *seems* that the "crux" of the issue is Arduino->RPi comms doesn't work. If so, then troubleshooting options include: (a) use 'scope to view serial comms between Arduino & RPi; or (b) use known-good Serial->USB adapter (PL2303, FTDI etc) to connect Arduino serial o/p to PC, run Putty etc on PC and confirm that Arduino is actually sending expected data. Basically, reduce / split the "problem domain" into chunks & test each chunk.

Comment: Post a schematic of the connections of exactly what you have wired up here, please.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't connecting the raspberry pi to the arduino with the arduino's USB cable, then you probably have things wired up wrong.  You can't have two TX pins on the same trace, and you must cross-connect the TX and RX pins that need to communicate.  From what you've posted, it seems that you have the boards connected RX to RX and TX to TX.  The RX on the serial chip on the arduino board is connected to the TX pin on the microcontroller so you should only see traffic FROM the arduino in the arduino serial monitor.  If you see traffic from the raspberry pi in the arduino serial monitor, then you've wired it up wrong.